# Showing Inequalities for a unit in a real quadratic field depending on its discriminant

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $u > 1$ be a unit of $K = \mathbb{Q} \sqrt{d} $, where $d>0$ squarefree. Let $d_K$ its discriminant. For a homework, I want to show

$$ u \geq \left(\frac{\sqrt{d_K} + \sqrt{d_K -4}}{2}\right) \hbox{if} \ N_{K / \mathbb{Q}} (u) =-1$$

and

$$ u \geq \left(\frac{\sqrt{d_K} + \sqrt{d_K +4}}{2}\right) \hbox{if} \ N_{K / \mathbb{Q}} (u) =1$$

As a hint, it says, compute $Disc_{K / \mathbb{Q}} (1,u) = det \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1 (1) & \sigma_1 (u)\\
\sigma_2 (1) & \sigma_2 (u)
\end{pmatrix} $, where $\sigma_i : K \to \mathbb{C}$ are the embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$ and use $Disc_{K / \mathbb{Q}} (1,u) \geq d_K$. 
For $d \equiv 2,3 \ (4)$, I get for $u = a + b \sqrt{d}$, that $Disc_{K / \mathbb{Q}} (1,u) = 3b^2 \geq d_K = 4d$. Moreover $N_{K / \mathbb{Q}} (u) =-1 $ gives us $ a^2 - d b^2 = -1$. I have no idea how to advance from there. Any hints how you would solve this?

Comment: Did you make a typo ? $\sqrt{d_K\pm 4}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.

Comment: @reuns , I don't think so. It is just an upper bound, so I guess it does not have to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: If $u = a + b \sqrt{d}$ is a unit, then what is $1/u$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Hint 2: If $x + 1/x \ge \sqrt{d}$, then what lower bound can one put on $x$, assuming that $x > 1$? If $x - 1/x \ge \sqrt{d}$, then what lower bound can one put on $x$, assuming that $x > 1$?

**Added** Hint 3: If $u = a + b \sqrt{d}$ is a unit, then whether $a$ or $b$ have to be integers or are allowed to be half-integers depends on $d \pmod 4$. How does this change the relationship between Hint 1 and Hint 2? What lower bound could you get if $x + 1/x \ge 2 \sqrt{d}$?

Comment: Okay, if $u = a + \sqrt{d} b$ is a unit, then $(a + \sqrt{d} b)(a + \sqrt{d} b) = N((a + \sqrt{d} b)) = \pm 1$ So, $\frac{1}{u} = \pm (a - \sqrt{d} b)$. For the 2nd hint, as $x>0$, one gets $(x \mp \frac{\sqrt{d} - \sqrt{d-4}}{2})(x \mp \frac{\sqrt{d} + \sqrt{d-4}}{2})=x^2 - \sqrt{d} x \pm 1 \geq 0$. So, in one case I get $x \geq \frac{\sqrt{d} - \sqrt{d-4}}{2}$ and in the other case, I did not check yet. This looks nice so far, I just have one problem. I am supposed to show it for $d_k$ and $d_k = 4 d$ if $d \equiv 2,3 \ (4) $.

Comment: Okay I worked it out now for $d \equiv 2,3 (4) $. For $d \equiv 1 (4)$, we should have $ u = \frac{a + \sqrt{d} b}{2}$. Writing $1/u$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ should work out the same way: $1/u = \frac{a + \sqrt{d} b}{2}$. Thus, for $N(u) = -1 , 1 + 1/u = \sqrt{d}b \geq \sqrt{d} = \sqrt{d_K}$. So, somehow it turns out to be the same from here as for $d \equiv 2,3 (4)$. Is that right? Why did you hinted at the inequality with $2 \sqrt{d}$?

Comment: @MPB94, Honestly, you asked for a hint, and I gave you three. Think about what happens when $d \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$ some more.